# How can i add several forms in MainForm of C#.Net?

Tags: c#

I want to add several forms in MainForm of C#.Net.
We can go to next form with Form like that.

```
Form frm=new Form2();
frm.ShowDialog();
```

like that.If we go with that method,Form2 will apper with new form.Not in MainForm.
I want to do following picture.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFYlV.png

How can i do that?
I'm just new baby in C#.Net.
Sorry for any mistakes for my question.
Please let me know if you can.
Thanks you for your time.

Comment: The screen-shot shows *one* form.  Drag controls from the toolbox and drop them on your form.

Comment: do you need to access to the MainForm as well when Form2 is shown or only to Form2? because your code above is correct in case you want to have Form2 open in modal way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A form which can contain other forms is called an MDI form. CodeProject has a [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/mdiformstutorial.aspx) on them.

Comment: Very Thanks you. I'm looking like that. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use MDI forms. To create a MDI (Multiple Document Interface), you have to set `Form.IsMdiContainer=True` in property windows.

For more information please take a look at MSDN article - [Multiple-Document Interface (MDI) Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xyhh2e7e.aspx)